# Why am I getting a type-error in this libp2p code?

Tags: go, libp2p, go-libp2p

I'm trying to initialize a connection between two `libp2p.Host` instances.  For this I need to get a `peerstore.PeerInfo`.  The obvious way to do this is to take a `multiaddr.Multiaddr` instance returned by `Host.Addrs` and pass it to `peerstore.InfoFromP2pAddr`.

Simple, right?

Here's some code that does just that:

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/SentimensRG/ctx"
    "github.com/SentimensRG/ctx/sigctx"

    libp2p "github.com/libp2p/go-libp2p"
    pstore "github.com/libp2p/go-libp2p-peerstore"
)

var c = ctx.AsContext(sigctx.New())

func main() {
    h0, err := libp2p.New(c)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    h1, err := libp2p.New(c)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    addr0 := h0.Addrs()[0]
    peerinfo, _ := pstore.InfoFromP2pAddr(addr0)  # type error here
}
```

The above code will not compile.  The compiler returns the following error:

```
# command-line-arguments
01-basic-conn/main.go:25:39: cannot use addr0 (type "gx/ipfs/QmYmsdtJ3HsodkePE3eU3TsCaP2YvPZJ4LoXnNkDE5Tpt7/go-multiaddr".Multiaddr) as type "github.com/multiformats/go-multiaddr".Multiaddr in argument to "github.com/libp2p/go-libp2p-peerstore".InfoFromP2pAddr:
    "gx/ipfs/QmYmsdtJ3HsodkePE3eU3TsCaP2YvPZJ4LoXnNkDE5Tpt7/go-multiaddr".Multiaddr does not implement "github.com/multiformats/go-multiaddr".Multiaddr (wrong type for Decapsulate method)
        have Decapsulate("gx/ipfs/QmYmsdtJ3HsodkePE3eU3TsCaP2YvPZJ4LoXnNkDE5Tpt7/go-multiaddr".Multiaddr) "gx/ipfs/QmYmsdtJ3HsodkePE3eU3TsCaP2YvPZJ4LoXnNkDE5Tpt7/go-multiaddr".Multiaddr
        want Decapsulate("github.com/multiformats/go-multiaddr".Multiaddr) "github.com/multiformats/go-multiaddr".Multiaddr
```

This appears related to `gx`'s path management, but I'm not exactly sure how.  My only interaction with `gx` was when installing libp2p in the [recommended way](https://github.com/libp2p/go-libp2p#install), namely running `make && make deps` from the libp2p root, which is semantically equivalent to:

```
gx --verbose install --global
gx-go rewrite
```

What gives?  **What do I have to do in order to compile my program?**

Comment: Your code seems to work in my setup. I'm running docker image: golang:1.10, I've installed gx and libp2p, initialized it with make's and run `go run main.go`.

Comment: Also works for me. The value of `addr0` is `/p2p-circuit` and `peerinfo` is `<nil>`.

Comment: @xReprisal @Devin How did you install libp2p?  Did you run the `gx` commands?

Comment: I've run make && make deps. I did not run any `gx` command.

Comment: @xReprisal `make deps` runs a series of `gx` commands.